# iOS 14 Widget background refresh not happening - how to get diagnostics / refresh budget counter information?

Tags: ios, swift, widget, ios14, widgetkit

We are trying to update our home widget around 4 to 5 times an hour within a 10 hours period a day after our application reaches a given state (we can not predict when exactly this will happen).

When the application is in the foreground, everything works fine and as expected, is the application **in the background** though, the widget gets refresh maybe once an hour or **not at all** (background processing is enabled and working properly) . It feels totally random and currently we simply can't retrace or comprehend what is happening or why it is happening.

This is our **TimelineProvider**:

```
struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> Void) {
       let preferences = UserDefaults.init(suiteName:widgetGroupId)
       let title = preferences?.string(forKey: "title")

       let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), title: title ?? "")
       completion(entry)
    }
    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        ...
    }

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
                getSnapshot(in: context) { (entry) in
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .never)
            completion(timeline)
        }
    }
}
```

Our application tries to update the home widget via `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()`.

I have now the following questions:

1. How can I understand why the refresh is not working and when it will be possible again? Is there something like a cooldown time?
2. How can I check the refresh budget counter? Can we obtain it somehow in the code?
3. How can I reset the budget counter for testing? Shall I recreate the widget? Restart the phone? Reinstall the app?

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, calling reloadAllTimelines() from anywhere but the foreground app seems to be unreliable. Instead of setting your timeline expiration policy to .never, try using .after with a date 15 minutes or so in the future. That should ensure your widget is updated ~4x an hour with the latest data. Hopefully that’s close enough for your use case.